# I've got a stack with this API Respond data

Tags: php, arrays, api

Let's to the point :
I've got respond code like this

> string(141)
>   "000|0123456789|**0987654321|namexxxxx|081xxxx|10000|1231231230|namexxxxxx|081xxxx|10000|3213213210|namaxxxxxx|081xxxx|10000**|page|total_page"

(I've make it bold for the main data)

There's 3 main data. The main data is dynamic( the ID is in front of name, the last data is "10000"), and max is 10 loop's. How I can take the main data with PHP ?
Help :)

Comment: you can start with $array = explode('|', $string);

Comment: explode function just can be used in not dynamicaly separator data :( see my reply at maxjackie's answer...

Answer (score 1):

explode the string with function `explode`

```
$array = explode ( '|' , $string );
print_r($array);
```

find out the desired data on the array index

[explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: yes,it's can usefull if the data is not dynamic. but the main data is dynamic, data start at 0987654321|namexxxxx|081xxxx|10000 and there's 3 data now... :(

Answer (score 1):

the best practice I found that work for me is to create an index array and work with it, you already know what each param is represented, so I'll create named array elements to help me work with my respond data.

```
<?php
$key = array(
    'code1' => 0
    'code2' => 1
    'code3' => 2
    'name' => 3
    'code4' => 4
    ...
);
$data_str = "000|0123456789|0987654321|namexxxxx|081xxxx|10000|1231231230|namexxxxxx|081xxxx|10000|3213213210|namaxxxxxx|081xxxx|10000|page|total_page";
$data = explode('|',$data_str);

$response_name = $data[$key['name']];
```

hope this helps.

Comment: explode function just can be used in not dynamicaly separator data :( see my reply at maxjackie's answer...